# TypeError: this.props.searchMovie (Redux Action) is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Am new in `React.js`, and am facing an error in Redux when I call it as a prop with the help of `mapStateToProps`.

This is my class

```
import {Component} from "react";
import React from "react";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {searchMovie,fetchMovies} from "../actions/searchActions";
export class SearchForm extends Component{


    onChange = e => {
        this.props.searchMovie(e.target.value);
    };

    onSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        this.props.fetchMovies(this.props.text)
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div className="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid mt-5 text-center">
                <div className="container">
                    <h1 className="display-4 mb-3">
                        <i className="fa fa-search" /> Search for a movie
                    </h1>
                    <form id="searchForm" onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            className="form-control"
                            name="searchText"
                            placeholder="Search Movies"
                            onChange={this.onChange}
                        />
                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-bg mt-3">
                            Search
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    text: state.movies.text
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps,{searchMovie, fetchMovies})(SearchForm)
```

If you closely look at `onChange()`, this is where the error comes from , when I try to type in the input, the exception is thrown :

```
 onChange = e => {
            this.props.searchMovie(e.target.value);
        };
```

Then my Root component is here :

```
import React from 'react';
import '../styles/App.css';
import Navbar from "../components/Navbar";
import Footer from "../components/Footer";
import {Landing} from "./Landing";
import store from "../store/store";
import {Provider} from "react-redux";

function App() {
  return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Navbar/>
            <Landing/>
            <Footer/>
        </Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Then how I made my `actions` :

```
import {SEARCH_MOVIE} from "./types";


export const searchMovie = text =>  dispatch => {
    dispatch({
        type: SEARCH_MOVIE,
        payload: text
    })
}
```

Then, the `Reducers`

```
import { SEARCH_MOVIE} from "../actions/types";

const initialState = {

    text: '',
    movies :[],
    loading: false,
    movie:[]
}


export default function (state = initialState, action) {

    switch (action.type) {
        case SEARCH_MOVIE:
            return {
                ...state,
                text: action.payload,
                loading: false
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

`reducer/index.js`, is where I combine my reducers :

```
import {combineReducers} from "redux";
import searchReducer from './searchReducer'


export default combineReducers({
    movies:searchReducer
})
```

Then finally my `store` :

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux'
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import {composeWithDevTools} from "redux-devtools-extension";
import rootReducer from '../reducers'

const middleware = [thunk]
const initialState = {};

const store = createStore(rootReducer,
    initialState,
    composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware)))

export default store
```

Can anyone tell me where am wrong ?

Comment: Am I right in assuming you're importing `searchMovie, fetchMovies` before using them?

Comment: What do you mean by this @Sasha and which file ?

Comment: in your class file, you should have something like `import { searchMovie } from "./actions"` or something along those lines, before you use it

Comment: @Sasha, I have updated my question, the imports are there

Comment: But still nothing works

Comment: Have you tried removing the function in your reducer? export default function => export default

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen the mapDispatchToProps done like you have before. Try this:

```
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import actions from "../actions/searchActions";

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch);
export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(SearchForm);
```

If this doesn't work, you've got a deeper nested problem with the way you have setup redux

Answer (score 0):

```
 const searchMovie = text => dispatch => {
    dispatch({
      type: SEARCH_MOVIE,
      payload: text
    });
  };
 export default searchMovie;
```

Try this in the searchActions file and remove fetch movie functions from everywhere **{remove it from the search form in the connect function, the import statement, and onSubmit function }**. It will work right now, then open redux from redux extension in the chrome browser and see the state if it changes when you start typing or not. and guess what it will change without errors:)

---

After that add the fetchmovie function in **searchActions file** and make sure that you also add it as a second case in the reducer file **cause you missed it.** Also, **add it into the search form as the second parameter in the connect function, the import statement, and in the onSumbit function.**

***Add this in searchActions***

```
export const searchMovie = text => dispatch => {
dispatch({
  type: SEARCH_MOVIE,
  payload: text
 });
 };

export const fetchMovie = text => dispatch => {
axios
  .get(`https://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=${APIKey}&s=${text}`)
  .then(response =>
    dispatch({
      type: FETCH_MOVIES,
      payload: response.data
    })
   )
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };
```

***And add this in reducer file***

```
  case FETCH_MOVIES:
            return{
                ...state,
                movies: action.payload,
                loading: false
            };   
        default:
            return state;
    }
   }
```

after that, it will work.